# gnuradio companion flowgraph error of source/sink IO size mismatch with hier block parameter

Tags: parameter-passing, gnuradio-companion

I have a hier block that takes as a parameter the length of the input vector that is fed to the block from a top level flowgraph and uses it internally, such as to specify the Pad Source vector size. But GRC would give me source/sink IO size mismatch error whenever the value of the parameter set in the top flowgraph does not match the initial/default value set for the parameter in the hier block. The initial value set in the hier block should not matter as it should take the value passed in from the top flowgraph. But it does not appear so in this case as GRC seems to use this initial value to determine the Pad Source vector size and hence produces an error message saying the expected input size does not match that of its source. How would I go about solving this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue. I would advise that you open an issue on the [Github page](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio).